# Show information from internet in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I want show information from internet in one DialogFragment and I have some doubts, bellow:

1 - To do this, I implement a AsynkTask in DialogFragment, but my activity run another AsynkTask in the same time, so dialogfragment need wait finish the AsynkTask from activity. Is possible execute AsynkTask from DialogFragment before of activity?

2 - I try use one DialogProgress in DialogFragment, but it's showing in activity, how to he in DialogFragment?

3 - Is possible consult information from internet in DialogFragment without AsyncTask?

```
public class DialogFotoFragment extends DialogFragment {

private String latitude;
private String longitude;
private Handler hndl = new Handler();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_foto_ponto, container);

    // Verifica se a latitude e lngitude foram informados
    if (latitude == null || latitude.trim().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),
                "Não foi possível apresentar a foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        this.dismiss();
    }

    if (longitude == null || longitude.trim().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(),
                "Não foi possível apresentar a foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        this.dismiss();
    }

    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fotoPonto);
    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnOKDialogFoto);

    btn.setOnClickListener(buttonOk);

    ProgressDialog pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
            "Wait...", true);

    // Apresenta tela de aguarde
    ConsultaFotoBackGround consultaFoto = new ConsultaFotoBackGround();
    Object[] objs = new Object[3];
    objs[0] = img;
    objs[1] = this;
    objs[2] = pDialog;
    consultaFoto.execute(objs);
    return view;
}

private OnClickListener buttonOk = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        DialogFotoFragment.this.dismiss();
    }
};

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

private class ConsultaFotoBackGround extends
        AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object[]> {

    private Handler hndl = new Handler();
    Drawable fotoInternet;
    ImageView img;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected Object[] doInBackground(Object... objs) {
        img = (ImageView) objs[0];
        DialogFotoFragment classe = (DialogFotoFragment) objs[1];
        pDialog = (ProgressDialog)objs[2];

        try {
            fotoInternet = Utilities.LoadImagePonto(latitude,
                    longitude);
            showFoto();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(classe.getActivity(),
                    "Não foi possível apresentar a foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            classe.dismiss();
        }
        return objs;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object[] result) {
    }

    protected void showFoto() {
        hndl.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                img.setImageDrawable(fotoInternet);
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you get the info you need using the `AsyncTask` and then in its `onPostExecute` you can create a `DialogFragment` with the data you have just got.

Follow the official documentation to know how to properly create a dialog (even with a custom layout): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html